# XPath for relative element in table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm using Java Selenium to open links based on the title as input.
I have following part of HTML in which `Top 5 Item Exception Types` is title I need to find and its hyperlink `<a class="CatalogActionLink" href="javascript:void(null)">Open</a>` is in another `<tr><td><span>` tag next to its sibling`<tr><td><span>` tag. How can I find element `Open` hyperlink by searching title `Top 5 Item Exception Types`?

```
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="CatalogObjectListItemIcon" rowspan="2"><img src="/analytics/res/sk_blafp/catalog/obj_request_b.png" alt="Analysis" title="Analysis"></td>
            <td><span class="CatalogObjectListItemTitle">Top 5 Item Exception Types</span>
                <span class="CatalogObjectListItemLastModifiedTime">Last Modified 2/15/2018 12:39:45 PM</span>
                <span class="CatalogObjectListItemOwner">Owner System Account</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a class="CatalogActionLink" href="javascript:void(null)">Open</a></td>
                            <td><span class="CatalogActionLinkSeparator">&nbsp;</span>
                            </td>
                            <td><a class="CatalogActionLink" href="javascript:void(null)">Edit</a></td>
                            <td><span class="CatalogActionLinkSeparator">&nbsp;</span>
                            </td>
                            <td><a class="CatalogActionLink" href="javascript:void(null)" title="Click to see more actions of Top 5 Item Exception Types">More<img border="0" src="/analytics/res/s_FusionFX/uicomponents/obips.UberBar/dropdown_n.png" alt="Dropdown menu">
                            </a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can find title using following

```
WebElement reportElement = driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//span[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'"
                            + reportName.toLowerCase() + "')]"));
```

Comment: how open and Top 5 Item Exception Types are related ? I did not get this part !

Comment: 'Open' is hyperlink for report with title 'Top 5 Item Exception Types'

Comment: You want to click on hyperlink ?

Comment: Kindly makes the question clear please. Give some ease to the one who is trying to help you please.

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes, I want to open hyperlink for 'Open' by searching 'Top 5 Item Exception Types'

Comment: @waghso : You can refer my answer. Hope It will work for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
//span[text()='Top 5 Item Exception Types']/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr/descendant::a[text()='Open']
```

Comment: getting following erro `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='top 5 item exception types']/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr/descendant::a[text()='Open']"}
`

Comment: use Top instead of top

Comment: please copy the exact same xpath which I have given, it is working fine in my machine. Just make sure the table should not be in any frame.

Answer (score 2):

Try this xpath -- `"//span[.='Top 5 Item Exception Types']//ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr//a[.='Open']"`

Comment: getting following error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='top 5 item exception types']//ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr//a[.='Open']"}` do we need to consider `<td>` as well?

Comment: You have a small case 't' in Top, change that to 'T'. I copied your html and tried it out, it works with the xpath i gave.

Answer (score 2):

Both @Grasshopper and @cruisepandey answers are good (+1). This is just a little shorter version for the same:

```
//tr[.//span='Top 5 Item Exception Types']/following-sibling::tr//a[.='Open']
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer... Reduces the dependency on the html structure to a greater degree.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the *WebElement* with text e.g. **Open**, **Edit** or **More**, with respect to the *WebElement* with text as **Top 5 Item Exception Types** you can write a function which will accept the reference text i.e. *Top 5 Item Exception Types* and the desired **action** (i.e either *Open*, *Edit* or *More*) as an input argument and locate the relevant *WebElement* as follows:

```
public void clickOperation(String title, String operation)
{
    WebElement opsLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/span[.='" + title + "']//following::tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr//td/a[@class='CatalogActionLink'][.='" + operation + "']"));
}
```

You can call the function `clickOperation()` along with reference text i.e. *Top 5 Item Exception Types* and the required *operation* as a `String` an arguments from anywhere within your script to identify the relevant *Link WebElement* of the respective **Top 5 Item Exception Types** *item* as follows :

```
clickOperation("Top 5 Item Exception Types","Open")
// or
clickOperation("Top 5 Item Exception Types","Edit")
// or
clickOperation("Top 5 Item Exception Types","More")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this xpath, it finds your text and then gets back for a few levels, then searches again for specific 'a' element.

```
//td/span[contains(text(),'Top 5 Item Exception Types')]/../../..//td/a[text()='Open']
```